# Simple perl issue related to gt and >

Tags: perl, comparison

```
$load_traff = 36333298;
$value =    1205553404; 

if ( $load_traff gt $value ) {
   print("Inside if. \n");
}
else{
   print("Out of if. \n");
}
```

### Output

```
Inside if.
```

Why does the above code give incorrect answer while below code gives correct answer?

```
$load_traff = 36333298;
$value =    1205553404; 

if ( $load_traff > $value ) {
    print("Inside if. \n");
}
else{
    print("Out of if. \n");
}
```

### Output

```
Out of if.
```

Comment: Both give correct answers, just not the answer you were expecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'gt' operator does  a string comparison (along with lt, eq). $load_traff is "lexically" greater than $value.

Comment: Thanks Jarred. I thought that 'gt' once seeing numbers would do normal  number comparison.

Comment: Nope; but if you have a string of numbers, you can still use > < == operators.

Comment: Perl is not about to do a number comparison when you specifically asked it to do a lexical comparison by using `gt`.